Enviar correo automatico
Tengo un formulario en una landing page que es para un registro sencillo, nombre, correo y whatsapp, ya estos datos los tengo cargados en un Google Sheet y envía la información de manera correcta los 3 datos a las 3 primeras columnas, comparto el script del formulario
 <div class="mw-event-form-wrapper">
        <form id="mw-event-form">
            <h2>Inscríbete al evento MW <br><span>¡GRATIS!</span></h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Nombre</p>
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Tu nombre" required maxlength="20">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Correo electrónico</p>
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Tu correo electrónico" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>WhatsApp</p>
                <input type="tel" id="whatsapp" placeholder="Número de WhatsApp" required pattern="[0-9]{7,15}">
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="terms" required>
                <label for="terms">Declaro haber leído y aceptado la política de tratamiento de datos personales de acuerdo con la normativa vigente en Colombia dispuesto en la Ley 1581 de 2012 y demás normas que la reglamenten, modifiquen o complementen</label>
            </p>
            <button type="submit">INSCRIBIRME AL EVENTO</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Ventana modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h2>¡Felicidades!</h2>
            <p>Tus datos han sido registrados exitosamente.</p>
            <button id="modalCloseBtn">Aceptar</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const form = document.getElementById('mw-event-form');
        const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        const modalCloseBtn = document.getElementById('modalCloseBtn');
        const scriptUrl = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxb_CmZ8Qjus9rqMFwdwtBT7D33CTomhHJNBPZY y el resto';

        form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
            const whatsapp = document.getElementById('whatsapp').value;

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', name);
            formData.append('email', email);
            formData.append('whatsapp', whatsapp);

            fetch(scriptUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data); // Para debuggear, puedes imprimir la respuesta
                modal.style.display = "block"; // Mostrar la modal al recibir respuesta
                form.reset(); // Limpiar el formulario
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
        });

        // Cerrar la modal al hacer clic en el botón "Aceptar"
        modalCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        });
    </script>

Ahora lo que deseo es poder que cuando lleguen los datos al Google Sheet, se envie un correo automático, para ello estoy usando este script en el Apps Script
function doPost(e) {
    try {
        const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AQUI VA EL ID DE MI SHEET').getActiveSheet();
        const formData = e.parameter;
        sheet.appendRow([formData.name, formData.email, formData.whatsapp]);

        // Configuración del correo electrónico
        const emailAddress = formData.email; // Dirección de correo electrónico del destinatario
        const subject = "¡Gracias por registrarte en nuestro evento MW!";
        const message = `
            <h2>¡Hola ${formData.name}!</h2>
            <p>Gracias por registrarte en nuestro evento MW. Estamos emocionados de tenerte con nosotros.</p>
            <img src="URL_DE_TU_IMAGEN" alt="Imagen de agradecimiento" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;">
            <p>Saludos,<br>El equipo de MW</p>
        `;

        // Enviar el correo electrónico
        MailApp.sendEmail({
            to: emailAddress,
            subject: subject,
            htmlBody: message
        });

        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Form submitted successfully!' })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    } catch (error) {
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Error: ' + error.message })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
}


function testDoPost() {
    const testData = {
        parameter: {
            name: 'Prueba',
            email: 'wprueba@gmail.com',
            whatsapp: '1234567890'
        }
    };

    // Llamar a la función doPost con los datos de prueba
    const result = doPost(testData);
    Logger.log(result.getContent());
}


Cuando ejecuto la prueba si me llega el correo de prueba, pero cuando recibo los datos aunque quedan en mi Google Sheet no se envia el correo automatico, y ejecuto la funciona doPost y ejecuta completa y sin error.

claro es algo que ya revise, pero me indica mas informacion al respeto de reenvio automatico pero no relacionado a la recepcion de datos desde google sheet

Cuando envías los datos desde el formulario, ¿estas seguro de que los datos llegan en e.parameter y no en e.postData.contents?

es muy raro, porque yo hago el test pra probar los servicios de correo, y me hace la prueba perfecta envia toda la informacion que esta en el cuerpo, pero es solo cuando llega el formulario que no envia el correo automatico aunque si llena los datos en el sheet
